# How to disable the warning of Unnecessary Using of Directive in vscode?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, editor, visual-studio-code

I am currently using VS code develop my game with Unity.

Every time I open the editor, there is a 99+ Unnecessary using of directive which makes me unhappy. Since there are lots of dependency of 3rd party plugins, I'am not sure weather I can remove them. So I want to have some method to disable them.

I tried something like:

```
"csharp.lint.unnecessaryUsingDirective": "ignore"
```

But obviously, it doesn't work. So I wish there would be something I can do to hide or disable this warning.

Answer (score 4):

I think this [issue has already been addressed](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn/issues/301) in the latest version of Omnisharp — but because we are forced to use the legacy C# extension for Unity, the solution remains unclear.

We *should* be able to add something like this to an `omnisharp.json` file in our project root:

```
{
    "IgnoredCodeIssues": [
        "^Unnecessary using directive.$"
    ]
}
```

But presently, this throws an error:

```
System.FormatException: Unsupported JSON token 'StartArray' was found.
Path 'IgnoredCodeIssues', line 2 position 27.
```

I have opened a [new issue specifically for the legacy C# extension](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/526), in hopes that it gets some feedback from the Omnisharp-VSCode team.